# How to handle partial reads with read() function in C

Tags: c

I have to implement standard unix command "tail" without fopen, fclose, fread, fseek, printf. I am ready with everything else except handle of partial reads and writes.

And here is my print with handle of partial read and write of last 10 lines. It's happening after lseek to the right position for fd!

I test it several times with different files and it works like real tail, but i cant handle partial reads and writes like i said.

'''code'''

```
    do
    {
        
        memset(buff, 0, SIZE);

      
        read_value = read(fd, buff, SIZE);
        ssize_t bytes_read_total = read_value;
        int count=2;
        char buff_copy[SIZE];
        while (bytes_read_total < SIZE)
        {
            read_value = read(fd, buff + bytes_read_total, SIZE - bytes_read_total);
            if(count%2==0)
                strcpy(buff_copy, buff);

            if (read_value == -1)
            {
                char *err;
                err = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(50+strlen(file)));
                strcpy(err, "tail: error reading '");
                strcat(err, file);
                strcat(err, "'");
                perror(err);
                free(err);
                return 2;
            }
            if(read_value==0)
            {
                strcpy(buff, buff_copy);
                read_value = strlen(buff_copy);
                break;
            }
            bytes_read_total+= read_value;
        }


       
        ssize_t bytes_written;
        ssize_t bytes_written_total = 0;
        while (read_value != bytes_written_total)
        {
            bytes_written = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff+bytes_written_total, read_value - bytes_written_total);
            if (bytes_written == -1)
            {
                perror("tail: error writing 'standard output'");
                return 3;
            }
            bytes_written_total += bytes_written;
        }
    }while(read_value);
```

'''code'''

Comment: I'd argue you have a worse problem: You use the data in the buffer you read into *before* you check if data actually was put into the buffer. And you treat the data as a null-terminated string even before you know if it really is that.

Comment: You don't have to handle partial read. Just what you read, then write. You have to handle partial write. It's not `read_it_all(); write_it_all();` it's `while (read(part, ...)) {  write(part, ...); }`

Comment: If you're on Linux and the code doesn't have to be portable to other systems, then you could use the [`sendfile`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) system call to "copy" data from one descriptor to another in an effective way. Without having to worry about partial reads or writes. The BSD variants (which includes macOS) have [a similar function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendfile&sektion=2)